# How to rotate secondary y axis label so it doesn't overlap with y-ticks, matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to rotate my secondary **y-label** to `270 degrees`, but when I do this passing the `rotate=270` argument it overlaps my **y-tick** text. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df.index,df.tripTime,label='Fishing Effort', marker='D')
ax2=ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(tr.index,tr.cost, 'g',label='Fuel Expenditure', marker='d')

lines = ax.get_lines() + ax2.get_lines()
ax.legend(lines,[line.get_label() for line in lines], loc='lower left')
ax.set_ylim((0, 18))

ax2.set_ylabel('Cost ($)',color='g', rotation=270)

for tl in ax2.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('g')

ax.set_ylabel('Fishing Effort (hrs)')
ax.set_xlabel('Time (days)')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**UPDATE: This answer isn't very good, please look at the comments!**

This looks like a bug and you should probably report it to [matplotlib's issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues).

While it is getting fixed, a quick solution is to set the label padding to a higher value:

```
ax2.set_ylabel('Cost ($)', color='g', rotation=270, labelpad=15)
```

[image: Result]

Moreover, negative `labelpad` values can be used to decrease the white-space as well.

Comment: Link to github issue for anyone stumbling across this: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5920

Comment: [tacaswell](https://github.com/tacaswell) pointed out on the issue tracker that the proper solution is to set the appropriate vertical alignment for the new rotation in the call to ``set_ylabel``, i.e. here ``va='bottom'``.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once.  You have no idea how long I've been trying to resolve this issue.

Comment: @TravisJ the solution I gave in this answer isn't the correct one though. Refer to the one tacaswell gave on the bug tracker, with ``va='bottom'`` - that's the way it is intended to be done.

Comment: @pmos, thanks.  I did use the suggestion in the comment.  I suggest, rather than refer readers of your answer to the comments, that you include the comment in your answer.  That way, if the comment is ever deleted (for whatever reason) the content is still available.  Plus, the goal of editing your answer is to make it better--so when you learn something new, edit it into your answer and make your own answer better.

Comment: In my case, I'm using a y-axis label on the right that is *not* a secondary axis.  That is, I'm using `plt.gca().yaxis.set_label_position("right")`.  For anyone doing this, this needs to be done *before* `plt.gca().set_ylabel("...", rotation=270, va="bottom")`.